# satellite orbit propagation from initial position and velocity

Tags: artificial-satellite, two-line-elements, propagation

I'm trying to get the satellite orbit at a certain time given the initial position and velocity (SGP4) say I have a TLE file that is taken in epoch:(2022-01-05 11:25:15.578) and I need to get the position and velocity for the next two days or next 100 orbits for example. how can I do this in python using TLE set to initial position and velocity?

Comment: Many copies of this question have already been answered on this site.  Please look at https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/25967/sgp4-propagation-initialization-by-state-vector and https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/57584/calculating-satellite-position-and-velocity-from-tle , then search on "TLE SGP4" and read some of what comes up.  Then, if that still doesn't answer your question, please be more specific about how it doesn't.